# Como verificar a INEXISTÊNCIA de um diretório em um servidor FTP no Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus, object-pascal

Uso o `Delphi` e o `Lazarus` para criar minhas aplicações, o que devo fazer para verificar a **inexistência** de um diretório contido em um **Servidor FTP**?

Por exemplo, quando vai checar a **inexistência** de um **arquivo local**, se usam os comandos:

```
(if not DirectoryExists('C:\Teste') then)
```

**Como fazer o mesmo em um servidor FTP?**

Comment: Você esta utilizando TChilkatFtp2 ? se tiver você pode fazer um  ftp.ChangeRemoteDir('CaminhoDaPasta'); e colocar em um if, ele retorna 1 se existir, joga o else caso não exista http://www.example-code.com/delphiAx/ftp_dirExists.asp

Answer (score 1):

Se você usar Indy (veja em www.indyproject.org/Sockets/index.EN.aspx), nessa biblioteca tem um componente chamado TIdFTP que tem o método List() e a propriedade DirectoryListing. Execute List() e depois processe os resultados em DirectoryListing para verificar quais arquivos e diretórios estão presentes no servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Como disse o colega acima **Aguena**, você pode usar a procedure **List** do componente **TIdFTP**

```
  var Lista := TStringList.Create;
  IdFTP.List(Lista, specified, details);
  for var I := 0 to Lista.Count-1 do
  begin
    if FileExists(specified) then // Aqui verifica se Existe
    begin
      // DoSomething
    end;
  end;
```

Usando Variável inline, usando Delphi 10.3